# HTML form radio value in an AJAX-loaded div

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, radio-button

I'm unable to get a radio value in a form loaded by AJAX into a div.
Here is the JavaScript code I'm using:
(the radio  name is 'categorie_add' in get function):

```
function getCheckedValue(radioObj) {
if(!radioObj)
    return "";
var radioLength = radioObj.length;
if(radioLength == undefined)
    if(radioObj.checked)
        return radioObj.value;
    else
        return "";
for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
    if(radioObj[i].checked) {
        return radioObj[i].value;
    }
}
return "";
```

}

```
function get(obj) {
    var poststr ="cat_title=" + escape(encodeURI(document.getElementById("cat_title").value )) +
                 "&cat_description=" + escape(encodeURI( document.getElementById("cat_description").value ))+
                 "&cat_id=" + escape(encodeURI( getCheckedValue(document.categorie_add.cat_id) ));
    makePOSTRequest('categorie.php', poststr);
}
```

and I have this in a PHP file:

```
            echo '<li><input type="radio" name="cat_id" id="cat_id" value="' . $value['cat_id'] . '" /> ' . htmlentities($value['cat_title']) . '<br />';
```

Comment: Can you post your "makePOSTRequest" ?

Comment: There's not enough context to say what your problem is, but there are a few potential traps in there. It looks like you may be creating multiple elements on the page with `id="cat_id"`; this is invalid and will confuse `getElementById`. You should be using `encodeURIComponent()` on values being inserted into URL segments, not `encodeURI()` which is for whole URLs, and definitely not `escape()` which is utterly bogus and should never be used for anything. Prefer `htmlspecialchars()` to `htmlentities()` which will mess up non-ISO-8859-1-encoded characters.

Comment: Note that if you use `someElement.getElementsByName()` to pick up the `name="cat_id"` inputs, instead of old-school `form.elementname`, you'll always get a list, so you can avoid having to check for the nasty single-element special case in `getCheckedValue()`.

Comment: these comments solved my problem.
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the problem is in the way you catch the radio object in DOM ....

Please write too the code how make the call to the function `getCheckedValue`.

#### Try in Jquery way...

```
$('#cat_id:checked').val();
```

Jquery is Rock.

#### JavaScript function:

```
function getCheckedValue(radioObj) {
  for ( var i in radioObj )if (radioObj[i].checked) return radioObj[i].value;
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to read this tutorials:

```
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_radio_checked.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_methods.asp
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say the problem is the way you generate your radio buttons:

```
echo '<li><input type="radio" name="cat_id_' . $value['cat_id'] 
   . '" id="cat_id_' . $value['cat_id'] 
   . '" value="' . $value['cat_id'] . '" /> ' 
   . htmlentities($value['cat_title']) . '<br />';
```

Try to get jQuery to make your life simple. You could get your values like that:

```
$('#cat_ul input[type=radio]:checked').val();
```

(assuming your <li> tags are wrapped in a <ul id="cat_ul"> tag)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what marvinlabs says, try to use chrome development tools to see what happening on the code return by ajax. You will see what the exact ajax responseText and also the contents of the Headers sent to the server. This also include the field and its value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep on not using jQuery, change your code to the following:

```
function getCheckedValue(radioObjArr) {
  if(!radioObjArr)
    return "";
  for (var ii = 0; ii < radioObjArr.length; i++) {
    if (radioObjArr[ii].checked) {
      return radioObjArr[ii].value;
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

And

```
function get(obj) {
  var poststr ="cat_title=" + escape(encodeURI(document.getElementById("cat_title").value )) +
             "&cat_description=" + escape(encodeURI( document.getElementById("cat_description").value ))+
             "&cat_id=" + escape(encodeURI( getCheckedValue(document.getElementsByName("cat_id")) ));
  makePOSTRequest('categorie.php', poststr);
}
```

Your current code is unclear, though. You use an ID ("cat_id") on your radio button, but your getCheckedValue-function also supports getting an array of objects. An ID has to be unique, though.
I changed your code a little so you'll always use an array of objects, even if it has only one element.